# My custom reports work fine, but mail_report fails

Tags: email, civireport, cron, 5.15.2

All of my custom report mail_report jobs give this error, both through cron and when triggered manually:

> "Did not find valid instance to execute"

The report is defined as

```
class com_foo_bar extends CRM_Report_Form {
```

It is stored as an extension in

```
[civicrm.files]/ext/custom
```

For example, report 70 works fine in a webbrowser .. it is at

https://mydomain.com/bla/civicrm/report/instance/70

But the mail_report job log says

> Entity: Job Action: mail_report Summary Finished execution of yyy with result: Failure, Error message: Report Mail
>   Triggered... Did not find valid instance to execute Details
>
> Parameters raw (from db settings):  instanceId=70 format=csv
>
> Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
>   a:3:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:10:"instanceId";s:2:"70";s:6:"format";s:3:"csv";}
>
> Full message:  Finished execution of yyy with
>   result: Failure, Error message: Report Mail Triggered... Did not find
>   valid instance to execute

The same happens when called from the command line. If job.mail_report is called on a regular report, it returns results. But if it is called on my custom reports, it returns

```
$ drush -u cron civicrm-api job.mail_report instanceId=70 format=csv sendmail=0 
Report Mail Triggered...                                                                                                                                                                             [error]
Did not find valid instance to execute
Array
(
    [is_error] => 1
    [error_message] => Report Mail Triggered...
Did not find valid instance to execute
)
```

or

```
$ php bin/cli.php -s mydomain.com -u cron -p XXXXXX -e Job -a mail_report --instanceId=70 --format=csv --sendmail=0
Report Mail Triggered...
Did not find valid instance to execute
Died during callApi
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: can you cross check that instanceId and format parameter on separate line for instance id 70?

Comment: You can see from the details it is parsed correctly - but also, when calling from the command line cli.php, both calls are 100% the same apart from the instanceId.

Answer (score 1):

What doesn't help, is that the code for Report.php:402

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Report/Utils/Report.php#L402

requires

```
if (strstr(CRM_Utils_Array::value('name', $templateInfo), '_Form')) {
```

and otherwise

```
  $is_error = 1;
  // ...
  $messages[] = 'Did not find valid instance to execute';
```

The 'name' reported for my custom report is more like

```
com.foo.bar
```

.. is that a bug, or some requirement I missed ?

Comment: Did you create it with [civix](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-report) or manually? For use with the standard extension autoloader it would end up in a subfolder CRM/Myextension/Form/Report/SomeReport.php and be called CRM_Myextension_Form_Report_SomeReport. So yes in a sense it's currently required to have Form in it, but it probably shouldn't be, and it shouldn't be enforced the way it is with strstr().

Comment: @demerit thanks for your response. I made them manually; CiviX didn't exist at the time I made those ... funny the problem only arises in the mail, not in the report online.